# Hello World for OpenGL+GLUT in Haskell not working on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, opengl, haskell, glut

The following program:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
main = do 
  (progname, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  createWindow "Hello World"
  mainLoop
```

compiled with the command:

```
ghc -package GLUT HelloWorld.hs -o HelloWorld
```

as explained on [this](http://blog.mikael.johanssons.org/archive/2006/09/opengl-programming-in-haskell-a-tutorial-part-1/) tutorial fails to execute on OSX Lion, displaying the following error message:

```
2013-09-07 20:31:20.372 aff[8561:60b] GLUT Warning: The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update your code.
2013-09-07 20:31:20.373 aff[8561:60b] GLUT Fatal Error: redisplay needed for window 1, but no display callback.
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm not on OS X and could not reproduce the error (nor the warning for that matter). Furthermore I'm probably using different version of all the libraries. Note that these kind of differences between operating systems are (unfortunately) not that uncommon. When running the program I got a copy of the pixels underneath it, like the tutorial writer seems to expect.

The error message states

```
redisplay needed for window 1, but no display callback
```

Thus my guess is that you need to register the `displayCallback`. So, in line with the next part of the tutorial, I added

```
displayCallback $= clear [ ColorBuffer ]
```

before the mainloop. Yet it did not fix the pixel carrying behaviour. To fix that I changed it to

```
displayCallback $= (clear [ColorBuffer] >> swapBuffers)
```

Which also updates the buffer on screen.

P.S. Note that the tutorial is from 2006, it might have bit rotted a bit. Furthermore OpenGL 2.1 was at that time the latest version of OpenGL.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem but the displayCallback doesn't seem to fix it.